# difference between php 5.3 and 5.6 with include path

Tags: php

We are upgrading our system from PHP 5.3 to 5.6 on an Apache 2.4.18 server running on Windows 7, we ran into a problem with include files.

We were using full path for our includes i.e.

```
include("c:\webSpace\Library\employee.php");
```

This runs just fine in 5.3.  But in newer versions 5.6 and 7, file names that started with and "e" were escaped so the executed code looked like this

```
include("c:\webSpace\Librarymployee.php");
```

We came up with two solutions:

1.escape the \ like so:

```
include("c:\webSpace\Library\\employee.php");
```

2. add the include path to the php.ini file like so:

   include_path = ".;C:\webSpace\Library"

and then the include would look like this:

```
include("employee.php");
```

My questions are these:

1.What happened between version 5.3 and 5.6 that caused this problem

2.Why do files not starting with "e" execute just fine like this:

```
include("c:\webSpace\Library\payScale.php");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is a result of the escape sequence `\e`, which is the ESC character (0x1B (27) in ASCII). This was added in PHP 5.4.4, which explains the difference between versions. This only occurs with that exact character sequence ("\e"), which explains why the other paths work fine.

Also, this only occurs within double-quoted strings, so another solution is to simply use single quotes around your paths.

Just to be clear, you would have similar issues if your paths used *any* of the escape sequences, such as `\n` (linefeed) or `\t` (tab). See the link below for a full list. It's just a consequence of using Windows-style backslash directory separators inside double-quoted strings.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation.  Very helpful.

Comment: Excellent. I'm glad that was helpful. If this solved your original issue, don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: @Claus Check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work